# Remove Layout from Single Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the `_ViewStart.cshtml` there's this code:

```
@{ 
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Which makes every view page imports it. What do I have to do when I don't want the page to load the `Layout.cshtml` on it's view at all? I only want to do it on SOME pages, not all of them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On those views, set the layout to null (or another layout).

Comment: You can even do it conditionally, checking for a certain value or parameter and setting it to null if appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

```
@{
       Layout = null;
}
```

add above code to the `view` (the one you don't want to show default layout).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using visual studio, when you're adding a view, you should get a screen where you can enter all your data about the view including a checkbox for "Use a layout page".  Just uncheck it and there you go.

If you're not or you just want to do it yourself, all it really does it just put the following at the top of your view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Hope this helps!